# Import json data as sass variables in an .scss file Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import json varialbes in a scss file so i can have them defined in 1 place and later use them in both scss and js.
The application is vue/nuxt

Have tried many variants but without success

Here is my code

src/assets/scss/test.json

```
{
  "danger": "#cc3333",
  "info": "#3399ff",
  "success": "#33cc99",
  "warning": "#ffcc00"
}
```

src/assets/scss/main.scss

```
@import "./test.json";

body {
  background-color: $info;
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

module.exports = {

  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],
  ...
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      ctx.loaders.sass.sassOptions.importer = jsonImporter
      console.log(ctx.loaders.sass.sassOptions)
    }
  }
}
```

Gives me error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                  friendly-errors 17:22:43  
SassError: Invalid CSS after "{": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
        on line 1 of assets/scss/test.json
        from line 1 of C:\Users\Fluksikarton\Desktop\nuxt-webserotonin-template\assets\scss\main.scss
>> {





extend (config, ctx) {
      console.log(ctx.loaders.scss)
      ctx.loaders.scss.scssOptions = {};
      ctx.loaders.scss.scssOptions.importer = jsonImporter()
    }
```

Gives

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'importer'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default export from `node-sass-json-importer` is a factory function, not the importer itself.

Also you are using SCSS not SASS ....

Change it to this: `ctx.loaders.scss.sassOptions.importer = jsonImporter()`

Comment: ahh true, but still it seems the way i extend the webpack config is not the right way. Changed it but still the same error

Comment: What version of `sass-loader` are you using ?

Comment: "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"

Comment: There are in fact 2 loaders - one for `sass` and one for `scss`. Updated my answer...

Comment: ctx.loaders.scss.scssOptions = {};

ctx.loaders.scss.scssOptions.importer = jsonImporter()



It gives me 

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: No! Loader is same type. Its just 2 instances - one for `sass` and one for `scss`. Use exact string as in my answer...